# React State listen for Object Attribute Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state

One of my components instantiates a class and stores it in the state. The Person class is used in many components.

```
// Car class
this.state = {
    driver: new Person(),
    passenger: new Person()
}
```

It then displays the location of the person

```
// Car class
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={this.state.driver.src} style={{left: this.state.driver.x, top: this.state.driver.y}} />
            <img src={this.state.passenger.src} style={{left: this.state.passenger.x, top: this.state.passenger.y}} />
            <span onClick={this.state.driver.moveRight}>Move Driver</span>
            <span onClick={this.state.passenger.moveRight}>Move Passenger</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The moveRight function being

```
//Person class
moveRight() {
    this.x += 1;
}
```

This avoids re-writing the Person.moveRight() method in all the components that need the person to be moved.

However, the state does not update when the car's attributes are updated, is there a way to fix this so the state updates appropriately, or is this not a good way to implement this?

Comment: Can you share more details especially about where `this.x` came from? And what does it do? Because it's look like just change variable value, not setState or forceUpdate to update the component.

Comment: you're mutating state when doing `object.prop` = `something`, so it wont trigger an update. You should do something like `setState((state)=> { return { driver:  { ...state.driver, x: state.driver.x+1 }  } } )`

Answer (score 2):

If you're considering to use a Function Component instead, this seems to be a perfect use case for implementing a [**custom hook**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

Create a `usePerson` hook and then use it in your `Car` Component. Here, give this a try:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function usePerson() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    src: "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-car/512/car-128.png"
  });

  function moveRight() {
    setPerson({
      ...person,
      x: person.x + 10
    });
  }

  return [person, moveRight];
}

export default usePerson;
```

And in your `Car` Component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import usePerson from "./usePerson";

function Car(props) {
  const [driver, moveRightDriver] = usePerson();
  const [passenger, moveRightPassenger] = usePerson();

  // console.log("Driver: ", driver);
  // console.log("Passenger: ", passenger);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <img
        alt="Driver"
        src={driver.src}
        style={{ left: driver.x, top: driver.y }}
      />
      <img
        alt="Passenger"
        src={passenger.src}
        style={{ left: passenger.x, top: passenger.y }}
      />
      <button onClick={moveRightDriver}>Move Driver</button>
      <button onClick={moveRightPassenger}>Move Passenger</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Car;
```

---

> Here's a [**Working CodeSandbox Sample**](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-useperson-hook-g9t5h) for your ref.

---

> **NOTE:** The images don't seem to move but if you un-comment the `console.log`s, you'll see that the `x` is indeed changing. So you might want to rectify that logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could a higher-order component paradigm. This proposal does not exactly match the UI you attempting to achieve but gets you closer to your desired functionality.

Notably, I would have each Person component (by way of the HOC paradigm) manage its own state rather than have that state managed by component in which it is rendered (i.e., Car).

```
const withMovement = RenderComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
     constructor() {
       super(props);
       this.state = { x = 0 }
     }

     moveRight = () => {
        const { x } = this.state; 
        this.setState({ x: x + 1 });
     }

     render() {
        return <RenderComponent moveRight={this.moveRight} xPosition={this.state.x} {...this.props} />
     }
  }
}

class Person extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super(props);
     // handle additional state here
   }

   render() {
     // Use xPosition props for display
     console.log('this.props.xPosition', this.props.xPosition);
     return (
       <button onClick={() => this.props.moveRight()} />
     )
   }
}

const Passenger = withMovement(Person);
const Driver = withMovement(Person);

class Car extends Component {
  constructor() {
     super(props);
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <Passenger />
        <Driver />
      )
   }
}
```